# Correct Syntax For Using The Returned Variable From A Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that returns a variable, I'd just like to know what's the correct syntax for doing something (such as doing math or writing a new variable using that returned variable.

Example Function:

```js
function exampleFunction(number) {
    var data_filter = number + number;
    return data_filter;
}
```

The function returns data_filter, and I'd like to know what's the correct syntax for doing something with it, such as inputting it in another function.

Comment: Assign it to a variable `result = exampleFunction(21)` or directly use it in another function call `anotherFunction(exampleFunction(21))`

Comment: that is indeed correct syntax!!! you can assign it to variable and OR pass it to another function.

Comment: `var other = exampleFunction(7) * 4`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping or use it in a statement :p

Comment: Nitpick: you don't return a variable but a value

Comment: `exampleFunction(...)` represents(evaluates to) whatever the return is.. you use it inside any expression..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is fine.

As one of the comment suggests typically you assign the result to a variable. Take a simple example here:

```js
let myNumber = 10;
let myHalvedNumber = halveNumber(myNumber);

console.log(myNumber)
console.log(myHalvedNumber);

function halveNumber(numberToHalve){
  return numberToHalve/2;
}
```

The best way to think about it in practice is to treat the function/input combination { f(x) } as a proxy for the result itself. This means that both of these examples are correct and how you choose to employ it is your own preference.

```js
//These two approaches are identical and both valid:

//1) Assign to a variable for further use - typically better for variable re-use:

let myHalvedNumber = halveNumber(10);
    aSecondFunction(myHalvedNumber);

//2) Use the result directly in a second call - typically shorter and arguably easier to maintain/read

    aSecondFunction(halveNumber(10));

function halveNumber(myNumber){
    return myNumber/2;
}

function aSecondFunction (myNumber){
    console.log("the number is: " + myNumber)
}
```